# Using services from ModuleWithProviders inside ErrorHandler

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, bugsnag

This one is bit of a pain and has had me stumped for a while now. Hoping you can help!

I have a module `UICoreModule` which houses a bunch of components, services etc. The services are provided via the `ModuleWithProviders` approach, as it gets bundled and published to npm.

I'm implementing a global error handler which logs to bugsnag using bugsnag-angular. That part works. What doesn't work is picking up the `UIToastService` to show a user message. It finds the service and appears to work and even reaches the `UIToastComponent` that picks up the toast and shows the message, but the message doesn't show. I have tried the `injector` approach using `this.inject.get(UIToastService)` to no avail.

What's also strange is that if the `UIToastService` has anything injected into is, such as `Router` I get a **Circluar Dependency** error at runtime.

Module looks a little something like this:

```
import { ErrorHandler, ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { UIToastComponent } from './components/toast/toast.component';

import { UIToastService } from './services/toast.service';

import { UIErrorHandler } from './handlers/error.handler';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        UIToastComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
        HttpClientModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        UIToastComponent,
    ]
})
export class UICoreModule {

    public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: UICoreModule,
            providers: [

                UIToastService,

                {
                    provide: ErrorHandler,
                    useClass: UIErrorHandler
                }

            ]
        };
    }
}
```

And the error handler...

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import BugsnagErrorHandler from 'bugsnag-angular';
import bugsnag from 'bugsnag-js';

import { UIToastService } from '../services/toast.service';

@Injectable()
export class UIErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    bugsnagKey: string;
    bugsnagClient: any;
    bugsnagErrorHandler: BugsnagErrorHandler;

    constructor(
        private uiToastService: UIToastService
    ) {
        this.setBugsnagKey('MY_BUGSNAG_KEY');
    }

    setBugsnagKey(bugsnagKey: string): void {

        if (bugsnagKey !== this.bugsnagKey) {
            this.bugsnagKey = bugsnagKey;
            this.bugsnagClient = bugsnag({
                apiKey: this.bugsnagKey
            });

            this.bugsnagErrorHandler = new BugsnagErrorHandler(this.bugsnagClient);
        }

    }

    handleError(error: any): void {
        this.bugsnagErrorHandler.handleError(error);
        this.uiToastService.error('some error');
    }
}
```

And the `UIToastService`...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { UIToast } from '../models/toast.model';

@Injectable()
export class UIToastService {

    toasts$: Subject<UIToast[]> = new Subject<UIToast[]>();
    toasts: UIToast[] = [];

    error(message: string): void {
        this.add(new UIToast({
            message: message,
            type: 'error'
        }));
    };


    add(toast: UIToast): void {

        this.toasts.push(toast);
        this.toasts$.next(this.toasts);

    }
```

}

And finally the `UIToastComponent`, which is placed in the `app.component.html` 
 file...

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

import { UIToastService } from '../../services/toast.service';
import { UIToast } from '../../models/toast.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'ui-toast',
    templateUrl: './toast.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./toast.component.min.css']
})

export class UIToastComponent implements OnInit{

    toasts: UIToast[] = [];

    constructor(
        private toastService: UIToastService
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.toastService.toasts$.subscribe((toasts: UIToast[]) => {
            this.toasts = toasts;
        });

    }

}
```

I literally square eyes from looking at this issue, eternal gratitude is yours if you can help in ANY way. I appreciate it's a bit of an odd one!

Thanks <3